# Div styles not extending to where Firebug says div extends to

Tags: html, css

I have this page: http://www.problemio.com/community/public_member_profile.php?member_id=1

It is supposed to have the gray background extend all the way below the footer.  If you look at it in firebug, it shows that the layout div contains a number of other divs.

So I don't understand why the gray background doesn't extend all the way down.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` at the end (before the close tag) of `div#layout`.

`clear:both` has to be added because of the floating inner DIVs. See also: [MDN: `clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear).

Comment: @GeekedOut **BEFORE** the closing tag. You've put it *after* the closing tag.

Comment: I think a solution with overflow:hidden (if u don't have absolute elements inside the #layout) is much better :) (u don't use a fake div without content)

Answer (score 1):

I believe with divs, the stack on top of each other. So your background div may have a grey color, when you open the next div it sits on top of it so to speak, which puts it in front of the colored div. Have you tried to apply the bg color class to another div inside the layout div to see if that is it?

Comment: I kind of thought that, but then when those inner divs are closed, the background should go back to the gray color, but even in the bottom of the page, the bg is still white, which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `overflow:hidden` to the container to clear it (if u have float children)

```
#layout{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Edit: or put a `clear:both` element as last child as a clear fix.

Comment: the overflow: hidden; did it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to the containing div. This will ensure that the container will wrap around all of it's content.

A useful tip when debugging is to put a bright border `border:solid 1px lime;` around the containing element to see how it is wrapping around it's child content.